# tty: navigate screen upwards

Tags: tty

I'm testing some scripts in a tty environment. There are some messages the script throws and I want to see them, but as the scripts continue, they remain up screen, not visible.

Is there a way to navigate screen upwards in a tty environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Alternatively you can use the `less` command as follow:

```bsh
$ your command | less
```

Comment: Problem is, when your script is running and printing new lines continuously in terminal. It always takes you to the end of output.

Comment: Thanks! I was messing with page down/up but didn't get the right combination.

Comment: @BlueManCZ you can use `Ctrl+s` to stop the output to the screen and `Ctrl+q` to allow the output to the screen.

Comment: @Loïc this is handy, thank you.